# How can I post an object with ngResource?

Tags: angularjs, django, ngresource

```
var send_data = {
  speed:{min:$scope.speedSlider.minValue,max:$scope.speedSlider.minValue}],
  f_temp:{min:$scope.f_tempSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_tempSlider.minValue},
  f_vol:{min:$scope.f_volSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_volSlider.minValue},
  f_den:{min:$scope.f_denSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_denSlider.minValue}
}

var settings = new Settings({truckId:$scope.truckId, data:send_data});

settings.$save();
```

I want to post this data to a Django backend and want the data to look like this:

```
data {
 speed {
   max: 120,
   min: 10
 }
}
```

But the network call shows this under Form data

> truckId:poc-truck1
>
> data:[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

To POST (create) a new resource object with AngularJS ngResource, use the `save` method.

```
var send_data = {
  speed:{min:$scope.speedSlider.minValue,max:$scope.speedSlider.minValue}],
  f_temp:{min:$scope.f_tempSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_tempSlider.minValue},
  f_vol:{min:$scope.f_volSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_volSlider.minValue},
  f_den:{min:$scope.f_denSlider.minValue,max:$scope.f_denSlider.minValue}
}

//var settings = new Settings({truckId:$scope.truckId, data:send_data});

var settings = Settings.save(send_data);
```

The RESTful API usually assigns a new ID and returns the new resource object with the ID attached as a property.